# How to retrieve the connections of a user in the LinkedIn API?

Tags: linkedin-api

I'm using the LinkedIn API to explore connections for a specific user. While querying the /connections/ endpoint, I anticipated a list of ARNs or a detailed list of connections. However, I received a response containing only the firstDegreeSize value.

{
"firstDegreeSize": 900
}

Is this the expected behavior, or am I missing something in my request? I'd appreciate insights on how to retrieve more detailed connection data using this endpoint. Thank you in advance!

In this [connection api article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/linkedin/shared/integrations/people/connections-api) which was written recently, it is said that we should be able to "By default, the Connections API returns a list of Person URNs only. To retrieve additional information about each connection, use decoration syntax to retrieve the id, first and last names."

So what i would like is the have the list of the connections of the encoded user in the get query and have the first name, last name of his connections.